# Update existing records based on the order from a different column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have the following table:

```
X_ID  X_NAME  X_TYPE  X_SORT_ID
 10    BOOK     1       NULL  
 20    PEN      1       NULL
 30    WATCH    2       NULL
  5    TENT     3       NULL
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to populate the X_SORT_ID column with incremented values starting with 1 based on value in X_ID.
So the table would look like this:

```
X_ID  X_NAME  X_TYPE  X_SORT_ID
 10    BOOK     1       2  
 20    PEN      1       3
 30    WATCH    2       4
  5    TENT     3       1
```

I need to update this table only for all existing rows.
The records that will be added in the future will use a sequence that would set the X_SORT_ID field to the next value.

The only query I came up with is not exactly what I need.

```
UPDATE X_ITEMS 
SET X_SORT_ID = (SELECT MAX(X_ID) FROM X_ITEMS) + ROWNUM
WHERE X_SORT_ID IS NULL;
```

I could use just a rownum, but this would assign value of 4 to the last record with X_ID = 5, which is not what I wanted.

I'd be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: As tagged, I'm using oracle10g with PL/SQL Developer

Comment: can use oracles [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) over `x_id`

Comment: how would you do that?
I've mentioned why I can't use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use oracle [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) :

**update query**

```
update items ot
set X_SORT_ID = 
( 
  select rw from 
  ( 
    select X_ID, row_number() over ( order by X_ID ) as rw from items
  ) it
  where it.X_ID = ot.X_ID 
)
;
```

**result table**

```
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
| X_ID | X_NAME | X_TYPE | X_SORT_ID |
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
|   10 | BOOK   |      1 |         2 |
|   20 | PEN    |      1 |         3 |
|   30 | WATCH  |      2 |         4 |
|    5 | TENT   |      3 |         1 |
+------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926a5/1)**

Comment: This looks great!
It does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using ROWNUM (a pseudocolumn) instead of ROWNUMBER(an analytic function) as used above.

[Read here for difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174595/in-an-oracle-database-what-is-the-difference-between-rownum-and-row-number)

> X_ID should be defined as primary key.

```
update Grentley GY
set X_SORT_ID = 
(select rno from 
     (select X_ID,rownum as rno from Grentley GY 
      order by x_id ) AB
where AB.X_ID= GY.X_ID
) ;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00126a/1)

[Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21fe9/1)